# Apache 301 redirect problems

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having a heck of a time configuring a 301 redirect in apache.

What I want is anything on old-domain.com to redirect to new-domain.com/notify/

I don't want pages redirected.  Meaning if someone goes to old-domain.com/page/blah.html, when they're redirected, I just want them to go to a subdir on new-domain.com, such as new-domain.com/notify/.

My 301 in the current apache config looks like this:

```
  Redirect 301 /page http://www.new-domain.com/notify/
  Redirect 301 / http://www.new-domain.com/notify/
```

That doesn't work.  With anything other than /page and /, 404 errors abound and it tried to redirect /page to http://www.new-domain.com/notify/page/

I'm wondering if a RewriteRule before the Redirect would help - just truncate all stuff that's not root.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `RewriteRule` to do the redirect directly.

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.new-domain.com/notify/ [R=301]
```

This would go inside your `<VirtualHost>` block for `old-domain.com`.

Comment: Perfect.  I'd forgotten about this.  Thanks!